# Preffix_Suffix Set for int Array [Programming]

Tags: java, algorithm

I have int array `int[] A = {3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 5};`

By definition:

> A prefix_suffix_set is a pair of indices `(P, S)` such that `0 ≤ P`, `S < N`
>   and such that:
>
> - every value that occurs in the sequence `A[0], A[1], ..., A[P]` also occurs in the sequence `A[S], A[S + 1], ..., A[N − 1]`,
> - every value that occurs in the sequence `A[S], A[S + 1], ..., A[N − 1]` also occurs in the sequence `A[0], A[1], ..., A[P]`.

My question is: Which is the list of prefix suffix set?

Comment: I imagine it is the list of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solutions are:

```
(P,S) -- prefix set - suffix set
(1,4) -- {3,5} - {3,5}
(1,3) -- {3,5} - {3,5} 
(2,2) -- {3,5,7} - {3,5,7}
```

Since `P <= S` is not required, these are also allowed (otherwise they would be excluded):

```
(2,1) -- the same as above, just having all the possibilities
(2,0) -- where P >= 2 and S <=2
(3,2) 
(3,1) 
(3,0)
(4,2)
(4,1)
(4,0)
(5,2)
(5,1)
(5,0)
```

So, the result is a set with the above-mentioned tuples. I suppose `N` is `6`, like the size of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using std::set;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

  int A[6] = { 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 5 };

  int countPS = 0;

  for ( int i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ) {

    set<int> P;
    P.insert( A , A + i );

    for ( int j = 5; j >= 0; j-- ) {

       set<int> S;
       S.insert( A + j, A + 6 );

       if ( P == S )
          countPS++;
    } 
  }
  cout << "The number of elements in list (P,S) = " << countPS << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Program Output:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3476 signal:0
The number of elements in list (P,S) = 14
```

http://ideone.com/8adJ1A

Comment: thanks !!! , code was not necessary.